# Having trouble getting my macro to recognize cell value

Tags: vba, excel

In the below script, it scans a sheet and will pull values, deleting ones that dont meet the set criteria in column "M". I can get it to work if I make the criteria fixed (in the below "MIGS Unavailable"), but if I try to refer it back to a cell (AI1) as the criteria, it either pulls every record or pulls none.

Your help please in allowing it to see the value in the cell as the criteria in the script!

```
Sub QuickCombine_MIGS()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim strShts()
Dim strWs As Variant
Dim lngCalc As Long

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
lngCalc = .Calculation
.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

Set ws1 = Sheets("MIGS-Datasheet")
ws1.UsedRange.Cells.Clear
strsub = Sheets("MIGS").Range("AI2").Value
strsub2 = Sheets("MIGS").Range("AI1").Value
strShts = Array(strsub)
For Each strWs In strShts
On Error Resume Next
Set ws2 = Sheets(strWs)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not ws2 Is Nothing Then
Set rng1 = ws2.Range(ws2.[v8], ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "v").End(xlUp))
rng1.EntireRow.Copy ws1.Cells(ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "v").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row, "A")
End If
Set ws2 = Nothing
Next
With ws1
    .[v1] = "dummy"
    .Columns("M").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>MIGS Unavailable"
    .Rows.Delete
.Rows("1").Insert
End With
With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.Calculation = lngCalc
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible. `.Columns("M").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" & .Range("AI1").Value` works for me the same as `.Columns("M").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>MIGS Unavailable"` if `AI1` contains "MIGS Unavailable".